# Save items added to scroll view android studios

Tags: java, android

I have created and been able to label items that have been added to a scroll view. I want to find a way to save and store the items created so that when the user clicks off the page they still remain there.

I wanted to do this through the use of sharedprefs however I am not sure how and where the best place would be to add code. Would appreciate any suggestions.

```
public class Editscreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    // https://codevedanam.blogspot.com/2021/04/dynamic-views-in-android.html

    Button add;
    AlertDialog dialog;
    LinearLayout layout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_editscreen);

        add = findViewById(R.id.button7);
        layout = findViewById(R.id.container);

        buildDialog();

        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {

                dialog.show();
            }
        });




    }

    private void buildDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog,null);

       EditText name =  view.findViewById(R.id.nameEdit);
       name.getText().clear();
       builder.setView(view);
       builder.setTitle("Enter Quiz name");
       builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                   addCard(name.getText().toString());

           }
       })
               .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                   }
               });

        dialog = builder.create();

    }


    private void addCard(String name) {
     View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cardlayout,null);
        TextView nameView = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        Button delete = view.findViewById(R.id.deletequiz);
        nameView.setText(name);

        


        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                layout.removeView(view);

            }
        });

        layout.addView(view);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can add this file to your project and you can call this static functions to save your data to pref. This is the compact way.

```
public class PrefUtil {
    private static SharedPreferences getPrefs(Context context) {
        return context.getSharedPreferences(context.getPackageName() + "_preferences",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    public static void setStringPref(Context context,String key,String deger){

        getPrefs(context).edit().putString(key,deger).apply();

    }

    public static String getStringPref(Context context,String key){

        return getPrefs(context).getString(key,"");

    }

    public static void setIntPref(Context context,String key,int deger){

        getPrefs(context).edit().putInt(key,deger).apply();

    }

    public static int getIntPref(Context context,String key){

        return getPrefs(context).getInt(key, -1);

    }
}
```